# Class#isAssignableFrom and unboxing/boxing

Tags: java, reflection, types

As we know, `Class#isAssignable` does not consider, that a value can be auto boxed/unboxed. E.g. the lower of the four following cases return `false`:

```
// obvious
System.out.println(boolean.class.isAssignableFrom(boolean.class)); // true
System.out.println(Boolean.class.isAssignableFrom(Boolean.class)); // true


// boxing/unboxing
System.out.println(boolean.class.isAssignableFrom(Boolean.class)); // false
System.out.println(Boolean.class.isAssignableFrom(boolean.class)); // false
```

Is there a pre-existing variant of this method which would consider this case? (i.e. returning `true` in all four given cases above.) If not, what would be the best way of implementing this for all primitive/wrapped combinations?

Comment: What is your use case? You'll never be able to call `getClass()` on a `boolean` anyway.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis he may be able, boolean.class (or Boolean.TYPE) may be passed as type using reflection.

Comment: @arne Those are, afaik, the only ways to get the `Class` object for `boolean`. So I fail to see the usefulness of knowing this information at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a WRAPPER_MAP field like this.

```
WRAPPER_MAP.put(boolean.class, Boolean.class);
// add others
```

then I look this up.

```
public static Class wrap(Class clazz) {
     Class clazz2 = WRAPPER_MAP.get(clazz);
     return clazz2 == null ? clazz : clazz2;
}
```

Then the test is

```
wrap(clazz1).isAssignableFrom(wrap(clazz2));
```

Comment: Although this does get the requested behavior, using `isAssignableFrom` is, imo, inappropriate given what it is meant to do. `boolean` is not the same class or a superclass of `Boolean`.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. By the way, I found that Apache Commons ``org.apache.commons.lang3.ClassUtils`` provides some useful methods for such cases (``#isAssignable``). @SotiriosDelimanolis I understand, that strictly the term 'assignable' might not be correct, but in my use case I need this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

This method is about subtyping, not whether one value can be assigned to a variable, which is much more complex, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2